# understanding range in python for loop

Tags: python

The program below is finding prime numbers in a given range. for the noprimes list comprehension part, why do we have 3 parameters in range?

```
noprimes = [j for i in range(2, 8) for j in range(i*2, 50, i)]
primes = [x for x in range(2, 50) if x not in noprimes]
print prime
```

and what is i doing there?

Comment: Step one: have you read the documentation? Documentation is good. It explains the answers to most questions like this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range):

```
range([start], stop[, step])
```

When comparing it to a `for(..; ..; ..)` loop e.g. in C the three arguments are used like this:

```
for(int i = start; i != stop; i += step)
```

There are also good examples in the docs:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(1, 11)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> range(0, 30, 5)
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
>>> range(0, 10, 3)
[0, 3, 6, 9]
>>> range(0, -10, -1)
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
>>> range(0)
[]
>>> range(1, 0)
[]
```

Answer (score 5):

For `range()`, the basic idea is that it generates a sequence of items for you. See this as reference http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range :

```
 format: range([start], stop[, step])
```

In the meantime here is some basic explanation, easiest example:

```
 range(5)
```

will generate numbers in the range starting at 0 (default start value) and go up to but *not* including 5, by increments of 1 (default value), so

```
 In [1]: range(5)
 Out[1]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You can specify additional parameters to range, such as the starting value, the ending value and also the stepvalue. So `range(startval, endval, stepval)`. Notice that `endval` is *not* included in the sequence that is generated.

```
 range(0, 5, 1)
```

is equivalent to

```
 range(5)
```

To generate all even numbers between 0 and 20 you could do for instance

```
 range(0, 21, 2)
```

Note that prior to Python 3 `range` generates a list and `xrange` generates the number sequence on demand.

In your specific code are using list comprehensions and range. It might be easier to understand the algorithm and the role of the for loops with range by eliminating the list comprehension temporarily to get a clearer idea. List comprehension is a powerful and efficient construct and should definitely be used if you plan on keeping the original code though.

```
#noprimes = [j for i in range(2, 8) for j in range(i*2, 50, i)]
noprimes = []
for i in range (2, 8):
   for j in range (i*2, 50, i):
      noprimes.append(j)

# primes = [x for x in range(2, 50) if x not in noprimes]
primes = []
for x in range(2, 50):
   if x not in noprimes:
      primes.append(x)
```

Comment: I have the same question here for the downvote, u almost said it all

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're stepping by `i` in *non-primes* to generate multiples of `i` (any multiple obviously a non-prime). `i` is in `range(2,8)` i.e. `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` because for primes till 50 you only need to eliminate multiples of numbers until `sqrt(50)` which is 7 (approximately).

If a nested list comprehension is confusing, try breaking it down into steps for easier understanding.

```
>>> [j for i in [2] for j in range(i*2, 50, i)]
[4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48]
>>> [j for i in [3] for j in range(i*2, 50, i)]
[6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48]
```

BTW, also look around online for better prime number algorithms. This one algorithmically very poor.

Comment: Thanks Praveen, wanted to understand list comprehension and range, itis clear now,will write it in a better algo now.

Answer (score 0):

The three parameters of range were explained by ThiefMaster. about the code - code looks ok to me. The only problem seems to be the `print prime` line. maybe you should add

```
for prime in primes :
   print prime
```