# Seeking clarification on the in range function in Python where the stop value is smaller than the start value

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the in range function.

I have read this post:
[understanding range in python for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267817/understanding-range-in-python-for-loop)

and am trying to clarify the example:

`in range(1,0)`
which delivers:
`[]`

The explanation says the in range functions like a `for(int i = 1; i != 0; i++)` in C, but I thought that would execute at least once with `i = 1` (and indeed in this case would never stop!), as the for loop happens at least once before checking the conditional for running again.

Can anyone explain the in range function in this particular case where the stop value is lower than the start value, and why it returns an empty list rather than the first item?

Many thanks

Comment: It is more like `for (int i = 1; i < 0; ++i)`. You don't have to actually hit the endpoint; you have to stay on the correct side of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the Python's range function work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738109/how-does-the-pythons-range-function-work)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python : what would be the ouput of range(x,y) if x>y](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413781/python-what-would-be-the-ouput-of-rangex-y-if-xy)

Answer (score 3):

All the `for` construct does is loop over an iterable. If that iterable is empty, then the body of the `for` is never executed.

All `range` does is return an interable containing all the values from `start` to `stop` (inclusive of `start`, exclusive of `stop`). If `start` is higher than `stop`, then the iterable is empty because there are no valid values between `start` and `stop`:

```
>>> range(0, 2):
[0, 1]
>>> range(2, 0):
[]
```

Putting this together means that you now have a `for` loop with an empty iterable - so it doesn't get iterated over at all.

If you wanted the numbers to count backwards, you can add a third argument to range of `-1` (called the `step`):

```
>>> range(2, 0, -1):
[2, 1]
```

What this does is tell `range` to go from `start` (inclusive) to `stop` (exclusive), but counting down instead (in steps of `-1`).

You can't *really* compare it to how the `for` construct in C works. Python's `for` is more like what is called `forEach` in a lot of languages.